# Using "with" clause

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, databricks

I'm trying to learn SQL/databricks platform and I'm having problems using this with clause in the notebook.

I'm trying to follow along with this tutorial. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think it has something to do with me using 'union'.Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/

```
with orgsrc
as
(

SELECT *
FROM vw_customers

UNION

SELECT *
FROM vw_customers_merge

)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
> mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'DESC', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DESCRIBE', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'REDUCE'}(line 13, pos 1)
> ```

Comment: Don't forget you need to SELECT from orgsrc too.

Comment: You need a `SELECT` after the CTE.  That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
WITH orgsrc AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM vw_customers

  UNION

  SELECT * 
  FROM vw_customers_merge
)
SELECT * FROM orgsrc
```

Some tips:

- write out the column list instead of using `*`
- use `UNION ALL` if you don't care about duplicate rows
- the data types and columns of all subsequent queries must match those of the first query in the `UNION`

Comment: thanks for the tips. Is there a reason I should write out the column list instead of * or is that just best practice?

Comment: My pleasure.  A couple reasons: 1) if any of the table definitions changes (i.e. add / remove a column), then the query will still work, 2) You can explicitly control the output data types of your result set, and 3) easier to follow / debug :)